# How to Install Scribus 1.5.3/4 on Ubuntu 18

Tags: command-line, software-installation, arabic, scribus

I need to know the installation procedures for this version of Scribus (which is a Devel. Version) on UBUNTU 18, because it supports arabic. I have already visited the website, and downloaded ppa over terminal, what's next.
P.S I need the Development version not the stable version 1.4.x

Answer (score 1):

Please see https://code.launchpad.net/~scribus/+archive/ubuntu/ppa.

Follow the instructions for adding the PPA to your system and install scribus-ng  (the latest Scribus development release) or scribus-trunk (the newest code as being committed by the team).

If you have further needs for support, please specify where you're stuck and I'll extend my reply with more information...